# A plant grows at a rate that slows by a third of its current rate every day ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Came across this question about rates that got me stumped. Is there a proper way to get some sort of function to solve it instead of using brute force?

> Assuming all conditions are perfect, and the environment is stable, find the height of a potted plant on the $28$th day, where the height of the plant $h$ is $1$cm on the first day and grows $6.5$cm every day, with the growth rate $r$ slowing by a third of its current rate every day.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The growth is a geometric series that you can sum.  Presumably the $6.5$ cm is the growth on the first day.

Comment: But then how would I factor in how it's slowing every day by a third?

Comment: It grows by $6.5$ on the first day.  It grows by $6.5\cdot \frac{2}{3}$ on the second day.  It grows by $6.5\cdot \frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{2}{3}$ on the third day and so on...  You can rewrite this into a standard form that you should have been taught already and get to the final solution directly

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming "6.5cm every day" is the starting growth rate.

Mathematically, we can express "the height on the 28th day" as follows:

$$h_{28} = 1+\sum_{i=0}^{27} 6.5\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^i = 1+6.5\left(\frac{1-(2/3)^{28}}{1/3}\right)$$

Where I got the last equality by the well-known formula for sum of the fist $n+1$ terms of a geometric series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula

Answer (score 0):

I believe rate of growth changes continuously.
Then $\frac{dr}{dt}=-k r$, $r=r_0 \exp(-kt)$. $r(t+1)=r(t)\cdot\frac{2}{3} \Rightarrow$ $\exp(-k)=\frac{2}{3}$.
Height $h(t)=h_0+\int_0^t r(t)\,dt=$
$h_0 + \frac{r_0}{k} \left(1-\exp(-kt)\right)=$
$h_0+\frac{r_0}{\ln (3/2)} \left(1-(\frac{2}{3})^t\right)$

Numerical value of answer will depend on $r_0$. There is two possible understanding of problem statement: 1. $r_0=6.5$. 2. $h(1)-h(0)=6.5$

1. $r_0=6.5$, $h_0=1$, then $h(28)\approx 17.03$.
2. $h_0=1$, $h(1)-h(0)=6.5$, $r_0=3\cdot 6.5 \ln (3/2)=19.5 \ln (3/2)$, $h(28)\approx 20.5$  and is exactly the same as in Bey answer.